# Retaining email address and some additional parameters with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise to manage users/registration. I am having a two=-fold issue:

1. If a mistake is made when filling the user registration form, for example one of the required fields is missing, when the form is re-displayed, the email field is missing (the other fields information is retained).
2. I have an additional field in the form that's not in the users table. This field is called code. When there's an error (described in #1 above), and the form is re-displayed, information for the code field is not retained either. If I look at the parameters in the log file, this field is a separate parameter (not part of the user parameter).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the info to re-display in the form just add params[:field] to that field. An example would be <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>.

You may have already figured this about by now but thought I would answer it anyways. If you want help on the other part just post your code :)